# Databricks spark.writeStream query is not faster with more workers

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks, delta-lake

Im trying to ingest data from Kafka topic and save it to delta with below code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

unit = 'V'
checkpointPath = "[checkpoint_path]" 
deltaPath = "[delta_path]" 

options = {
    "kafka.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
    "kafka.security.protocol" : "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers": "bootsrap-ip",
    "subscribe": 'topic',
     "startingOffsets": "earliest"
}

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(**options).load()

json_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("measurementYear", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("parameterType", StringType(), True),
        StructField("timeDifferenceSeconds", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("measurementStartTimestamp", StringType(), True),
        StructField("measurementEndTimestamp", StringType(), True),
        StructField("deviceSerialNumber", StringType(), True),
        StructField("unit", StringType(), True),        
        StructField("value", FloatType(), True)
    ]
)


def with_normalized_names(df, json_schema = json_schema):
    
    parsed_df = df.withColumn("body", F.from_json(df.value.cast("string"), json_schema))

    parsed_df = parsed_df.select(
        F.col("body.measurementYear"), F.col("body.parameterType"), F.col("body.timeDifferenceSeconds"), 
        F.col("body.measurementStartTimestamp"),  F.col("body.measurementEndTimestamp"),  F.col("body.deviceSerialNumber"),
        F.col("body.unit"), F.col("body.value"),  F.current_date().alias("regDate")
    )
    return parsed_df

write_query =  df.transform(lambda df: with_normalized_names(df)).writeStream.trigger(
        availableNow=True
    ).format("delta").option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath).start(deltaPath)

write_query.awaitTermination()
```

I deleted chekpointlocation folder, so every offest form the topic is saved to delta path.

I run this code in Databricks on Spark cluster with single node 14 GB memory and 4 cores, and it works fine.

Then I run the same code with the same data in the topic on multinode cluster with 2 workers, and I expected that it would work faster but it was not a case.

Can someone explain why adding extra workers didnt improve query performance? Shouldnt spark job be distributed in those workers? What can I do to ingest data faster?

I tried it on different cluster types but query time is always very similar.